# Excel VBA / SAP GUI: how to get Cell Text value on CV04N transaction?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have created an Excel VBA code to get some documents from SAP GUI. I can use the `CS03` transaction without any problem, I can read all the columns and rows. But on the `CV04N` transaction, I can not get any table value. Is there any way to get the for instance "FAT" as text at column 0 or "CONTROL CHART" from column 5?

[image: CV04N Screen]

After I create the connection, the code is as below.

```
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/ncv04n"
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsMAINSTRIP/tabpTAB1/ssubSUBSCRN:SAPLCV100:0401/subSCR_MAIN:SAPLCV100:0402/ctxtSTDOKNR-LOW").Text = "*XXXXXXXX*"
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsMAINSTRIP/tabpTAB1/ssubSUBSCRN:SAPLCV100:0401/subSCR_MAIN:SAPLCV100:0402/txtRESTRICT").setFocus
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsMAINSTRIP/tabpTAB1/ssubSUBSCRN:SAPLCV100:0401/subSCR_MAIN:SAPLCV100:0402/txtRESTRICT").cartPosition = 10
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

Set gridControl = objSess.ActiveWindow.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")                            
dataRowCount = gridControl.rowCount
```

The `rowCount` function works fine, but for the cell information, I cannot use `GetCell(0,0).Text`.

If anyone has an opinion and can share it with me, I will be glad.
Thanks

Comment: I've got no access to this transaction due to my role, but I've been doing such kind of things - just an advice - try to record script while putting the cursor to the cell you need. SAP will record the object selection. Most objects have the standard property ".Text" - so, you'll get the text of the cell

Comment: SAP GUI Scripting is never a matter of "SAP transaction", it's a matter of which GUI Element is shown. In your case, it's a [GuiTableControl object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiTableControl%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows). Impossible to tell you why "you cannot use" `GetCell(0,0).Text` if you don't provide code, if you don't say how to reproduce, and if you don't describe precisely the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved it in another way! I selected the whole table, copied it to the clipboard(you have to do it from SAP as well) then copied it to the Excel page. The rest you manage yourself on Excel.